# pop() and push() in copy constructor of template stack class not working

Tags: c++, templates, stack, copy-constructor

When I use `push()` and `pop()` functions of the original stack in copy constructor it gives me the following error:

> [Error] passing 'const Stack' as 'this' argument of 'void
>   Stack::pop() [with type = int]' discards qualifiers
>   [-fpermissive]

How to copy one stack into another using push and pop?

```
template <class type> Stack<type>::Stack(const Stack<type> & originalStk)
{
    MAXSIZE=originalStk.getSize();
    list = new type[MAXSIZE];
    top = -1;

    if(!originalStk.isEmpty())
    {
        Stack<type> temp(originalStk.getSize());
        while(!originalStk.isEmpty())
        {
            temp.push(originalStk.topVal());
            originalStk.pop();
        }
        while(!temp.isEmpty())
        {
            originalStk.push(temp.topVal());
            push(temp.topVal());
            temp.pop();
        }   
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: _"...it gives me error"_ what error?

Comment: @RichardCritten
it gives me the following error:
[Error] passing 'const Stack<int>' as 'this' argument of 'void Stack<type>::pop() [with type = int]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: What is `MAXSIZE`? In any case, it doesn't seem to be a runtime constant, meaning that `new type[MAXSIZE];` relies on non-standard extensions.

Comment: *How to copy one stack into another using push and pop?* Why would you do such a thing?  You have access to the underlying storage so why not just copy that?

Comment: A copy constructor should copy. This seems closer to what a move constructor would do. You cannot modify the parameter of a copy constructor, which `pop` would do.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux MAXSIZE is a private data member of class stack

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux
But it worked for non template stack class.

Comment: ***But it worked for non template stack class.*** It should not have worked for that either.

Comment: @ArslanArif It's not clear to me that you are aware that you have access to `originalStk`'s private members. Private members are accessible in your class' methods, regardless of if you access them with `this` or not. You can and should exploit this, specially when implementing constructors.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux
In copy constructor I can directly copy it's list but I have to use this method in other functions (client code) like I have to use push() and pop() methods in print function. If I can not use push and pop then please suggest me some alternative.

Comment: @ArslanArif It seems to me like you are trying to iterate over your `stack` using `push` and `pop`, which is very awkward, specially if your `stack` is `const`. If iteration is something you want to support with your `stack` implementation, you should implement iterators and `begin` and `end` methods. You should think carefully rather or not this is something you want to do to a `stack`. You may want to consider simply using a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux
Ok bro, Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

`const Stack<type> & originalStk` is a `const&` to a stack.

This means you are promising not to modify it through this reference.

`pop` modifies a stack.  Don't call `pop` on a `const&` to a stack.

Your code could be modified to support `template <class type> Stack<type>::Stack(Stack<type>&& originalStk)`.

It is, however, impossible to copy a stack without mutating it using `pop` and `push` and `topVal`.  You will have to write the copy constructor (taking a `const&`) using a richer interface to the stack.

As you are within the type, this is easy.

```
MAXSIZE=originalStk.getSize();
list = new type[MAXSIZE];
top = -1;
std::copy(originalStk.list, origialStk.list+MAXSIZE, (type*)list);
top = originalStk.top;
```

Now, your use of `new` and manual pointer lifetime management is code smell.  Replace `list` with a `unique_ptr<type[]>`, or all 3 state variables with a `std::vector<type>`.